# Cancelling Webpack watch task in Visual Studio task runner

Tags: visual-studio, npm, webpack, task-runner-explorer

I have a Visual Studio project which uses Webpack to bundle the client side code up.

I use the [NPM Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner) extension to actually run the tasks.

Originally I had the Webpack build command bound to the Visual Studio 'Before Build' event, so every time I wanted to recompile the JS, I had to do a full build.

I have now attached `webpack --watch` to the Project Open event, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429154/863487), which works great and recompiles the scripts as I modify them, but there doesn't seem to be a way to cancel this if, for some reason, I don't want it watching any more.

In a 'normal' set up, you would simply `Ctrl-C` to cancel the task, but since this is being run by the NPM task runner, there doesn't seem to be a way to access the actual terminal in order to cancel it. You can see the output in Task Runner Explorer, but there is no way to interact with the window.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer with webpack watch output]

Is there any way to cancel this task within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out one way by chance. You can just close the window in Task Runner Explorer.

[image: Screenshot of existing a process in task runner explorer]

Not exactly a mind blowing answer, but it does what I want it to.

Still open to better/less destructive answers.

Comment: Ctrl+Break to stop the build which should kill the watch